# Three.js globe rotate on click

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have created a rotating globe which has hostspots that fire a modal when clicked on. I would like the globe to spin and have the hotspot clicked on at the centre of the screen. The code below rotates the globe but doesn't centre it as desired. kindly provide pointers

```
 checkHotspotClick: function(){
        var me = this;
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(me.animate)
        //get normalized mousecoords -1 -> 1
        var mouse2DX = (mouseX/me.windowDimensionX)*2-1
        var mouse2DY = -(mouseY/me.windowDimensionY)*2+1

        //for use with a orthographic camera
        var vecOrigin = new THREE.Vector3( mouse2DX, mouse2DY, - 1 );
        var vecTarget = new THREE.Vector3( mouse2DX, mouse2DY, 1 );

        me.projector.unprojectVector( vecOrigin, me.camera );
        me.projector.unprojectVector( vecTarget, me.camera );
        vecTarget.subSelf( vecOrigin ).normalize();

        var ray = new THREE.Ray();
        ray.origin = vecOrigin;
        ray.direction = vecTarget;
        var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(me.hotspotsArr);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            console.log($(me.hotspotDivsArr[intersects[0].object.name]).html())
            // ajax overide
            me.targetRotation_x += (me.options.camX-mouse2DX)*12;
            me.targetRotation_y += (me.options.camY+mouse2DY)*12;
            me.doZoom(-6);
            console.log(me.targetRotation_x);
            var country_id = $(me.hotspotDivsArr[intersects[0].object.name]).data('id');
            url = 'home/getProjectData';
            $("#myModal").load(url,{ s: country_id });
            setTimeout(function() {$("#myModal").modal('show')},2000);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel($(this).data('slide-index'));
            /*me.targetRotation_x = 0;*/

            } 
            else
            {
                me.doZoom(+6);
            }
        },
```

Comment: Your best chance of getting help is to update to r.55 and provide a simple live example showing what you have so far.

Comment: Let me try that then will do a fiddle which i'd already started to do but then my project is on the localhost so attaching dependencies was put me off. thanks for taking your time though

Comment: Upgrading from r47 to 55 is like reprogramming again :-(

Comment: using r47 instead of r55 is like eating moldy food